# Intercept outgoing HTTPS for a .mp3 and sending a local file back on local machine

Tags: networking, https, discord

I dislike the discord message sound and want to change it.

When discord gets a message it makes an HTTPS request to a URL: https://discordapp.com/assets/dd920c06a01e5bb8b09678581e29d56f.mp3 . I want to know if it's possible to intercept that request and point it to a local .mp3 file on disk. I know little about security but this sounds like a man-in-the-middle attack I'm executing on myself.

So far I've tried using Fiddler to auto-respond to requests to that URL but it breaks discord (messages no longer send.) I've also considered running a Raspberry Pi as a middleman but I don't know if that supports very specific HTTPS requests, nor do I want my network bandwidth to be capped by routing all traffic through a Pi. Is this possible?